# Unable to log out of account

Tags: facebook, ipad, logout

My sister logged into her Facebook account on my iPad, she then logged out via the bottom button on the left hand side and left. My my wife went to check her Facebook account my sisters was still open. Again we logged out but it just reloads with her account open and we can access it by pressing continue. We tried deleting Facebook from the iPad. When we reinstall it her account is still accessible. She has also tried deactivating her account from her end but still no joy.

Comment: I flagged this for migration to SuperUser. Paul, your question may be more easily answered there. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming. Well said @lunchmeat

Answer (score 2):

In ios6 facebook is part of the operating system. Like ParrotMac said you need to change the login in settings. Try apple or facebook support if this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To log out, Go to the Home screen [home button] go into settings, scroll down to Facebook, and select Logout from the options.